# Align items top and bottom without using flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

There exist two items in a box and I'm trying to align the first item to the top of the box and the last item to the bottom of the box. I know I can do this easily with flexbox:

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Top text</div>
  <div>Bottom text</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the platform I'm using (some old html to pdf generator) doesn't support flexbox. Is there another way to do this without using flexbox?

Comment: The world is moving forward. Why do you need (some old html to pdf generator )?

Comment: More Old School than @Air is forwarding to, consider positioning your element in a relative parent container?

Comment: @Air, you'll find that many times developers, as cutting-edge as they may be, have to work within the confines of their clients' requirements. Sometimes, these developers only know modern technologies and, in order to learn about older technologies to meet their client needs, must come here to ask questions. Just something for you to consider.

Comment: @Michael_B, I agree with you, but the customer needs to be explained how to do better so as not to go with the customer who does not know what layout is ... We need to explain that, the further, the more difficult it will be to rewrite everything, move it to the level of new technologies ... This is my personal opinion ... The customer is always right and wrong ...)))

Comment: @Air, the customer is sometimes a large corporation forcing all employees to use IE11, or even IE9. The developer just wants to work, not revolutionize the company.

Comment: @Air for the record, this task is for a large corporation that's forcing me to use the older pdf generator. We're planning to use a newer/better generator in the near future but not at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS positioning properties.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
}

.container > div {
  position: absolute;
}

.container > div:first-child {
  top: 0; /* optional */
}

.container > div:last-child {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Top text</div>
  <div>Bottom text</div>
</div>
```

**Just note** that absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow. This means they don't respect the space occupied by surrounding elements, which can result in overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Just you can achieve using position relative and absolute as follow. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```css
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.container > div.top {
    bottom: inherit;
    top: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Top text</div>
  <div>Bottom text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the purpose of *inherit* here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea considering table where your elements will remain in-flow:

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  display: table;
}
.container > div {
  display:table-row;
}
.container > div:first-child {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Top text</div>
  <div>Bottom text</div>
</div>
```